# Form Validation Logic Problem ( Using React useState Hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

I am trying to do some form validation. I have two controlled elements in my form: a messages textbox and a recipients textbox. So, I have `state.message` (a string) and `state.recipients` (an array) which control some textboxes (when you type in the textboxes, these values of `state` change). The state is working properly. That is, when I type in the messages textbox, `state.messages` gets updated. When I type in the recipients box, `state.recipients` gets updated. `invalid` is defined with the `useState` hook like so:

```
const [invalid, setInvalid] = useState({
  message: false,
  recipients: false,
})
```

I want `invalid.messages` to be `true` when `state.messages` is empty, and `invalid.recipients` to be true when `state.recipients` is empty. Here is my validation code, which I am having some trouble with:

```
if (state.recipients.length === 0) {
  setInvalid({
    ...invalid,
    recipients: true,
  });
} else {
  setInvalid({
    ...invalid,
    recipients: false,
  });
}

if (state.message === '') {
  setInvalid({
    ...invalid,
    message: true,
  });
} else {
  setInvalid({
    ...invalid,
    message: false,
  });
}
```

My conditions *are* working, though. `state.recipients.length` is indeed equal to `0` when the recipients textbox is empty, and `state.message` is indeed `''` when the message textbox is blank. Now, the interesting part is that when both elements of the form are empty (that is, recipients and message are both empty), `invalid` is equal to

```
{
  recipients: false,
  message: true
}
```

This is extremely weird because I don't see any flaw in the logic I am using to change the state. The weirder part is that when I flip the if statements in this validation logic (that is, I check the message state first and **then** the recipients state) then the reverse happens: state looks like:

```
{
  recipients: true,
  message: false
}
```

I don't know why this is happening, so can you point out the flaw in my logic?

Edit: Some event handler code for the textboxes:
For the messages textbox: `onChange={(e) => { setState({ ...state, message: e.target.value }); }}`
For the recipients textbox (which intentionally overrides the first element in `state.recipients`):

```
onChange={(e, val) => setState({
  ...state,
  recipients: val,
})}
```

But this code really isn't the issue, because the state is being handled properly and it is empty when it supposed to be.

Comment: do you have any event handlers for the inputs ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how that would matter @JesseLucas

Comment: would you please include their code ?

Comment: @JesseLucas I have just done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State updates are asynchronous, so when call `setInvalid` and add the previous state using `...invalid`, the **same old state** is being used for both updates.

In other words, when the code you pasted is called, the first `setInvalid` to execute **doesn't finish updating** the state before the second one starts executing and pulls in the state using `...invalid`.

As a result, only `messaged` gets set properly.

You can likely resolve this issue by making both variables separate state objects.

```
const [invalidRecipiants, setInvalidRecipiants] = useState(true);
const [invalidMessages, setInvalidMessages] = useState(true);
```

Comment: Yay! Happy to help